# Mechanism of Peptization

Tags: surface-chemistry

Can somebody please explain the mechanism of Peptization(or give a link to the website which explain the mechanism step by step). The Mechanism given in my book is somewhat different from the mechanism given on the Wikepedia. Also the Wikepedia one is baffling me.
The wikipedia [Peptization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peptization) states

> The electrical charges present at the surface of the particles are so "neutralised" and disappear.

This process is same in the preparation of coagulated solution

> The electrical repulsion no longer hinders the aggregation of particles and they can then coalesce to form a flocculent precipitate that is easy to filter.

Again my book has exactly same para that this step is used in preparation of coagulated solution
And isn't peptization reverse of it that is that making of colloidal solution from splitting aggregating precipitate molecules, but here we are forming precipitate again.

> When colloidal particles bear a same sign electric charge.

Does wikipedia means precipitate particle here?

Also, how does coagulation differ from peptization. I mean one method to prepare a coagulated solution  is by adding electrolyte (containing ion of opposite charge ). In the process of peptization the only difference is that charge(should be opp charge) and one of the ion should be same as that in the precipitate. Does the mean in coagulation ion should  be different?

Comment: It would be nice to put both mechanisms (textbook vs. Wik**i**pedia) together in your question, or at least provide links/references so that others could have a basis upon which the differences could be discussed.

Comment: @andselisk i just want a whole new perspective that will clear my confusion.I dont have mobile  phone with me therefore cant put snapshot of my book but i can copy and paste wikipedia part  and tell where my book and it got differ.Should i do that?

Comment: Go ahead and do that, making sure to reference with a link.

Comment: In coagulation you cancel the surface charge to allow particles to come close. In peptization you do the opposite, you want the particles to repel each other.

Comment: The wikipedia article might be confusing you because it starts out by describing coagulation or flocculation. It then explains how peptization is the reverse of that. See also for instance: https://www.mrwa.com/WaterWorksMnl/Chapter%2012%20Coagulation.pdf

Comment: @BuckThorn is it correct to say depending upon the type of electrolyte that is added   coagulation or peptization will happen . In nutshell coagulation will happen if the the electrolyte added doesn't contain any common ion with precipitate .